# custom binary algorithm and neural network

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn

I would like to understand more the machine learning technics, I have read and watch a bunch of things on Python, sklearn and supervised feed forward net  but I am still struggling to see how I can apply all this to my project and where to start with. Maybe it is a little bit too ambitious yet.

I have the following algorithm which generates nice patterns as binary format inputs on csv file. The outputs and the goal is to predict the next row.

[image: pattern]

The simplify logic of this algorithm is the prediction of the next line (top line being the most recent one) would be 0,0,1,1,1,0 and then the next after that would become either 0,0,0,1,1,0 or come back to its previous step 0,1,1,1,0. However you can see the model is slightly more complex and noisy this is why I would like to introduce some machine learnings here. I am aware to have a reliable prediction I will need to introduce other relevant inputs afterwards.

Would someone please help me to get started and stand on my feet here?
I don't like throwing this here and not being able to provide a single piece of code but I am slightly confused to where to start.

Should I pass as input each (line-1) as vectors and then the associated output would be the top line? Should I build the array manually with all my dataset?

I guess I have to use the sigmoid function and python seems the most common way to answer this but for the synapses (or weights), I understand I need also to provide a constant, should this be 1?

Finally assuming you want this to run continuously what would be required?

Please would you share with me readings or simplification tasks that could help me to increase my knowledge with all this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do those numbers at the top (1,5,15,30,60,240) mean anything (i.t.o your data)?

Comment: What do you mean by "should I build the array manually"? If you have some input and output data, you just loop over that and extract / convert data to be passed to your NN (in a manner of your choosing). So you're going to need to write some code to do that, obviously, but you're not going to be manually copying over the data into a new representation.

Comment: How many lines back do you need to look to determine what the next line will be? What else does it depend on, if anything? That's probably the most important part of determining what the input to your NN should be (if you don't know, guess and try and repeat). N (=6 here) output nodes with each being 0 or 1 (or between 0 and 1) probably makes the most sense if your goal is predicting what any given line should be, assuming those don't represent some numeric data where a continuous representation would be better.

Comment: thanks for your comment Dukeling, those are labels of my data; no particular meaning for this exercise; I see what you mean; I missed the loop part, there are as many lines as needed as they are computer generated randomly but with a core relationship algorithm though, you cannot have or at least not likely to have 30 turning red suddenly in my example, it is fairly dependent of other state on its left becoming red before him. At the moment I don't have any other relevant input but the model should still be able to predict something which makes sense.

Comment: It will not yet be able to difference though between the two following output without other input : in my example  as next step 1 becoming green or 5 becoming red; however it should predict one or the other using a relevant training period ; I am so excited about it but seems like a huge step forward. I will try to copy the feedforward script in Python and minimise the error using the gradient descent and take it as a first step then, thanks.